# Design a Mysql Data for a maximum of performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Hello guys & thank you for helping

Each Player can play many characters. With each character, he has specific stats (Number of Kills, Deaths, Win Rate, number of games played etc). I have a table "PLAYERS" with all the players. I would like to rank Players by character according to one of the parameter (Win Rate for example). This ranking will be refreshed every hour, so my top priority is the speed of  the update.
My developer is suggesting me to create a table where each row represent the couple (Player, Character) and then there will be as many fields as stats.
I'm just worried about the future performance of such a table, because we have currently 10K Players in our base, around 100 characters for each player : 1Million rows.

But in the future, I expect there will be around 1Million players in the data base, which makes it 100Million Rows. Is it an optimal solution in term of speed?
I thought about using an additional single field in the table PLAYERS that would contain all the stats ("Win Rate : 50%; Number of Games played : 845 etc.). The size of the database will be 100 times smaller, but the process of ranking by charater will imply to search a Json field everytime, which might takes longer.

What do yo guys think?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: We are not a free consultancy service

Comment: Well dude  I'm a student & I'm passionated about games and I wanted to build a website. Sorry if I asked too much then

Answer (score 0):

Do what say your developer when you will have 1M players you will have money to change that if it is an issue... maybe it wouldn't be.

Using Json in MySQL is not the better way with MySQL and you had to update this json every time... https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/ Maybe you can do your JSON solution with MongoDB.

But you can use your point of view in table player adding stats fields on it and counting wins, looses... on player level not in character level if you don't need this on character level...